# Getting a 403 for static resources in spring boot without using spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat9

I have a spring boot application that is not using spring security at all, and when some requests come through for static resources, the server returns a 403.

The spring boot application is running in a tomcat 9 server (not embedded). A lot of the requests triggering the 403 come from mobile devices. I have read a lot of articles about this issue but they all refer to the spring security implementation which I am not using.

Has anyone experienced this? Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.valspar</groupId>
<artifactId>rest.valspar.com</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Valspar Web-Services</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.jdk>1.8</version.jdk>
    <ms.sql.version>1.0</ms.sql.version>
    <maven-git-code-format.version>1.31</maven-git-code-format.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- SpringBoot Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-discovery/commons-discovery -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/wsdl4j/wsdl4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc41 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>${ms.sql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/classes12 <dependency> 
        <groupId>oracle</groupId> <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId> <version>11.2.0.3</version> 
        </dependency> -->

    <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xml/serializer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>serializer</groupId>
        <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-partner-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>force-partner-api</artifactId>
        <version>44.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.smartystreets.api/smartystreets-java-sdk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartystreets.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartystreets-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mindscapehq</groupId>
        <artifactId>raygun4java</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mindscapehq</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pojava/datetime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>datetime</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/struts/struts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>wservices</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <filters>
        <filter>${basedir}/ci/profiles/build-${build.profile.id}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${version.jdk}</source>
                <target>${version.jdk}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.cosium.code</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-git-code-format</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-git-code-format.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- On commit, format the modified java files -->
                <!-- Un-comment the following execution block for the first build of 
                    the project. Revert to HEAD revision after project is built successfully 
                    for the first time. -->
                <!-- <execution> <id>install-formatter-hook</id> <goals> <goal>install-hooks</goal> 
                    </goals> </execution> -->
                <!-- On Maven verify phase, fail if any file (including unmodified) 
                    is badly formatted -->
                <execution>
                    <id>validate-code-format</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>validate-code-format</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I ran the application as standalone (without external Tomcat) and the problem does not seem to occur. This is pointing more to an interaction between the two or tomcat 9 configuration issue.

Comment: Could you show us your POM file and the web.xml file if it's available?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a tomcat 9 mis-configuration with a security realm and had nothing to do with Spring. The security real was not connecting to the user database so it was blocking anything static.